# Installing VS2015 Updates

Tags: visual-studio, updates

This is a very easy question but I'm having trouble finding an answer online. I just got a new PC from work and i'm about to install vs 2015 and it's updates. I have update 1,2 and 3. What I'd like to know is should I install all of them? or can I just install 3? Will the changes in update one and two be installed as well?

Answer (score 0):

The best choice is to download and install "Visual Studio 2015 Community 2015 With Update 3", from the official website:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx

If you install "With Update XYZ" (3 at the moment) you are sure that this is the latest available version, including all the patches and fixes. The Community edition is free, maybe you can install Professional or others edition.